# Potential pointer issue and Address is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Tags: c++, pointers, valgrind

I am getting a segmentation fault on one of my programs and not sure why. I've ran a valgrind:

```
==7631== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7631== Copyright (C) 2002-2009, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7631== Using Valgrind-3.5.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7631== Command: ./a.out wordsRMS.txt
==7631== Parent PID: 30431
==7631== 
==7631== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==7631==    at 0x403C5C: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::begin() const (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x403D04: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::size() const (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x40328A: testNewWord(std::string const&, std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >*) (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x4038FE: main (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631== 
==7631== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==7631==    at 0x403C86: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::end() const (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x403D11: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::size() const (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x40328A: testNewWord(std::string const&, std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >*) (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x4038FE: main (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631== 
==7631== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==7631==    at 0x403C5C: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::begin() const (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x403D04: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::size() const (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x405E78: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::_M_range_check(unsigned long) const (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x405EAC: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::at(unsigned long) (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x402DD2: testNewWord(std::string const&, std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >*) (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x4038FE: main (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631== 
==7631== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==7631==    at 0x403C86: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::end() const (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x403D11: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::size() const (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x405E78: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::_M_range_check(unsigned long) const (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x405EAC: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::at(unsigned long) (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x402DD2: testNewWord(std::string const&, std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >*) (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x4038FE: main (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631== 
==7631== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==7631==    at 0x403D48: __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>**, std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> > >::__normal_iterator(PeekDeque<StringWrap>** const&) (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x403D6C: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::begin() (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x403DD2: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::operator[](unsigned long) (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x405EB9: std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >::at(unsigned long) (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x402DD2: testNewWord(std::string const&, std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >*) (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x4038FE: main (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631== 
==7631== Invalid read of size 8
==7631==    at 0x402DD3: testNewWord(std::string const&, std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >*) (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x4038FE: main (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==  Address 0x6c894ce02464894c is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7631== 
==7631== 
==7631== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==7631==  General Protection Fault
==7631==    at 0x402DD3: testNewWord(std::string const&, std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*, std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap>*> >*) (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631==    by 0x4038FE: main (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631== 
==7631== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7631==     in use at exit: 9,344 bytes in 5 blocks
==7631==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 0 frees, 9,344 bytes allocated
==7631== 
==7631== 27 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 5
==7631==    at 0x4A0695E: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:220)
==7631==    by 0x33A9A9B860: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==7631==    by 0x33A9A9C23A: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==7631==    by 0x33A9A9CB44: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==7631==    by 0x33A9A9CD5E: std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==7631==    by 0x33A9A76203: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==7631==    by 0x40390B: main (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631== 
==7631== 37 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 5
==7631==    at 0x4A0695E: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:220)
==7631==    by 0x33A9A9B860: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==7631==    by 0x33A9A9C364: ??? (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==7631==    by 0x33A9A9C511: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8)
==7631==    by 0x403873: main (in /root/test/a.out)
==7631== 
==7631== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7631==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7631==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7631==      possibly lost: 64 bytes in 2 blocks
==7631==    still reachable: 9,280 bytes in 3 blocks
==7631==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7631== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==7631== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==7631== 
==7631== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7631== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==7631== ERROR SUMMARY: 8 errors from 8 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

The line that seems to be of importance:

`Address 0x6c894ce02464894c is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd`

However, I'm not quite sure what to make of this. Here is my code:

```
/** Add word to new or existing chain.
 */
void testNewWord(const string& word, vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>* >* chains) {
    bool foundChain = false;

    // check to see if we can add word into EXISTING chain
    for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != chains->size(); i++) {
        // check front of chain
        if(ed1(StringWrap(word).str(), chains->at(i)->returnFront().str())) {
            //cout << "The word has an edit distance 1 with the front item." << endl;
            chains->at(i)->pushFront(StringWrap(word));
            foundChain = true;
            break;
        }

        // check rear of chain
        if(ed1(StringWrap(word).str(), chains->at(i)->returnRear().str())) { 
            //cout << "The word has an edit distance 1 with the rear item." << endl;
            chains->at(i)->pushRear(StringWrap(word));
            foundChain = true;
            break;
        } 

    }

    // otherwise create a NEW chain
    if(!foundChain) {
        PeekDeque<StringWrap>* newpd = new PeekDeque<StringWrap>(500);  

        newpd->pushFront(StringWrap(word));

        chains->push_back(newpd);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){   
    if(argc != 2){
        cerr << "Please specify a SINGLE .txt file to generate word chains from." << '\n' << "Usage: ./PeekClientRMS /path/to/file.txt" << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>* >* chains;

    string word;

    string infileName = argv[1];
    ifstream* INFILEp = new ifstream(infileName.c_str(), ios_base::in);

    while ((*INFILEp) >> word) {
        testNewWord(word, chains);
    }

    INFILEp->close();


    /*for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != chains->size(); i++) {

    }*/

}
```

Interestingly enough, when I uncomment the for loop at the bottom of `main()`, my program runs?

```
/*for(std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i != chains->size(); i++) {

}*/
```

What could be going on here?

Comment: Avoid pointers and pass by value or reference (chains are not allocated)

Comment: Where is it allocated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `main` function you declare a pointer to a vector, but you never make that pointer actually point anywhere. Uninitialized local variables have an indeterminate value (and it will seem to be random), and using those variables leads to *undefined behavior*.

---

In this case there's no need to use a pointer for the vector. Just declare it as a normal non-pointer variable, and pass it to the function as a reference.

Like

```
vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>* > chains;
```

Then modify the function to take a reference:

```
void testNewWord(const string& word, vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>* >& chains)
```

---

In fact, in C++ you should try to avoid pointers as much as possible, they are often not needed. I would actually urge you to not store pointers in the vector.

Comment: So something like this? `vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>* > chains = new vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap>* >;`.

Comment: @Bob If it was Java then yes, or if you still kept it as a pointer. If you make the variable not a pointer, just remove the asterisk denoting that it's a pointer, and you're done.

Comment: @Bob No! Get rid of all new and pass by reference and value:  `vector< PeekDeque < StringWrap > >` and `void testNewWord(const string& word, vector< PeekDeque< StringWrap> >& chains)`

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is fundamental!

A pointer is no object, the `chains` is just holding an address to some memory, which is not the address of an object, not allocated and not initialized.

In C++ you should avoid needless allocations and prefer passing objects by value or reference:

```
vector< PeekDeque < StringWrap > > 

void testNewWord(const string& word, vector< PeekDeque< StringWrap> >& chains);
```

If you allocate via new you should pair up with delete, too (or delegate to a smart pointer).

The `ifstream* INFILEp = new ...` is a memory leak and defeats proper destruction without a `delete INFILEp` - better (again): omit the pointer and just use `ifstream INFILE(infileName.c_str());`

The `PeekDeque<StringWrap>* newpd = new PeekDeque` is likely a memory leak, too.

Comment: Great advice, thank you. I hope to not make this mistake again!